# Custom UICollectionViewLayout - Cells disappear after bounce

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uicollectionview

I've a simple UICollectionView with the CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout and 3 cells with a height between 300 and 400 pixels. The cells contain a view from a UIViewController which has a non-scrollable UITableView as subview.

It's all shown correctly but there is one problem. If I scroll to the bottom of the collection view on the iPhone and let them bounce one time, the last 2 visible cells disappear.

The cells are not higher than the screen of the iPhone. I also tried this in viewDidLoad:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:)]) {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

It doesn't change anything. The views in the cells are inserted by code, there isn't a XIB or storyboard for the cells. If I remove the line to insert the views the cells are still visible while and after the bounce. Does this mean it's a problem inside the UITableView?

Do you have any suggestion for me?

Thank you!

EDIT: The problem also reproducible when I hide the UITableView inside the subview.